# Why is the superlative form of "fertilis" "fertilissimus" rather than *fertillimus?

Tags: morphology, adjective, superlatives

Superlatives of adjectives ending in *-lis* are usually formed with the suffix *-limus*. For example, the superlative of *facilis* is *facillimus*. So, why is the superlative of *fertilis* *fertilissimus*, rather than *fertillimus*?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The superlative ending *-illimus* is actually exceptional, although the exceptional adjectives are quite common.
The adjectives with this superlative ending are
*facilis, difficilis, similis, dissimilis, gracilis, humilis*.
Other adjectives ending in *-ilis*, including *fertilis*, have the more regular superlative *-ilissimus*.

See [§126 in A&G](https://dcc.dickinson.edu/grammar/latin/comparison-adjectives).